# cassandra column data appears after a long delay and with incorrect timestamps

Tags: cassandra

I am using a cassandra column family with a Standard column type and a composite type key.  The cassandra cluster has 3 nodes, and a replication factor of 3.  Data gets inserted, updated and deleted from the column family.

For example, lets say the current state of the column family is

```
Row X  
column=1:a, value=v1, timestamp=1000  
column=1:b, value=v2, timestamp=1010  
column=2:a, value=v3, timestamp=1020
```

Many updates happen over a period of time where columns of `Row X` can get updated, and sometimes new rows get inserted or deleted.

The issue I am observing is that suppose say column with key 2:a is updated at `timestamp=1030` to a value of v4.  When I use cassandra-cli to observe the data, it does not show the key 2:a, even after several hours.  Later, keys 1:a, 1:b get removed and eventually - after after several hours, the key 2:a appears, but with a timestamp earlier than 1030 - say like 990.

I read that if there are clock discrepancies across nodes, then the writer that had the latest timestamp over writes the others.  If they are the same then the higher value trumps over lower value lexicographically.  But, in my case, there is just one writer process that updates the column family, and the writer updates just the key 2:a and later deletes 1:a and 1:b.  So there are no multiple writers for the same key.  The writer is multithreaded, so threads touch various keys, but not the same key.

So my questions are:

1. Under what circumstances can we have keys to not show up, even a very long time after a write has taken place?
2. What can cause the timestamp of the key to get messed up?  In the above example, 2:a should have had the timestamp of 1030, but showed 990 when it was eventually seen.

Can someone share some pointers on what could be wrong, or how to go about solving the issue, or any helpful articles to analyze the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Data isn't removed immediately by Cassandra. Columns are marked with a tombstone instead and will later be deleted by compaction, which explains your lag of several hours. Data in the ring with the highest timestamp is always chosen as the correct value, regardless of whether it's been marked as a tombstone. Although I couldn't be sure, node times being out of sync is most likely what's happening in your case. I would highly recommend that you install ntp on all of your machines, wait until all times are synced and try your testing again.